# Migrating from bootstrap 2.3.2 to 3.1.1

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently in the process of migrating my website from bootstrap 2.3.2 to 3.1.1. 
I'm having one problem, somehow one of my pages aren't looking well on Opera mobile (Android) or even the default android browser. That page is too much too one side.
You can find the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Brilliant-Minds/Brilliant-Minds.github.io/tree/bootstrap). The page in question is [infos.html](https://github.com/Brilliant-Minds/Brilliant-Minds.github.io/blob/bootstrap/infos.html). 
I think that container-narrow is the source of the problem, but i don't know what is the code that's causing this.

Comment: Have a look at: http://getbootstrap.com/migration/ and http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide

Comment: It looks like there is additional CSS too, so it's hard to isolate it as a Bootstrap issue

Comment: Neither the old non-Chrome stock Android Browser nor Mobile Opera are officially supported by Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the old non-Chrome stock Android Browser nor Mobile Opera are officially supported by Bootstrap: getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support 
Answer by: [Skelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171456/skelly)